# Find A when $A^{-1}B^{-1}=C^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$ A^{-1}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  1&2\\
  1&3
\end{array}
\right] $;
$ B=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  4\\
  6
\end{array}
\right] $;
$ X=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  x\\
  y
\end{array}
\right] $

Solve $AX=B$. If $A^{-1}B^{-1}=C^{-1}$, find A.

I was able to solve for $X=A^{-1}B\rightarrow \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  16\\
  22
\end{array}
\right] $

But I am unable to find A. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's unusual to talk about $B^{-1}$ when $B$ is a non-square matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by $B^{-1}$? $B$ is a vector.

Comment: Why do you need the condition $AX=B$ or $A^{-1}B^{-1}=C^{-1}$ (albeit this latter condition makes absolutely no sense) to find $A$?  If $A^{-1}$ is given, then $A$ can be readily computed.

Comment: That's how the question was set up. It's asked to solve for AX=B and then asked to find A, given $A^{-1}B^{-1}=C^{-1}$

Comment: I was baffled to see $B^{-1}$ as B is not a square matrix. However, the study guide has this question set up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $A$ by taking the inverse of $A^{-1}$. $$A=(A^{-1})^{-1}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  3&-2\\
  -1&1
\end{array}
\right]$$